# combine 2 data sources and display data on single table in power apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, power-platform, powerapps-collection

- work environment :  power apps
- data source : employee table and department table in sql server.
- the problem scenario :
  please, have a look on the diagram :
  [image: Combine table columns and create one single table to display on power apps.]

as per the diagram I want to display a table on the simple canvas app
which is a combined result of both employee and department table.

I have no idea how I could do that in power apps. tried many things maybe I am doing it in an incorrect way.

Comment: Want to display it in a table or a gallery?

Comment: No, I want to display it in a datatable

Comment: You can use the AddColumns function to add the data per row of what you need..
I.e. add the department name column with the lookup condition of department id.

Or, you just create a view in SQL with a JOIN clause and display that on the table.

Comment: can you please share any reference for this, because I am very new to this power apps environment and I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App > On Start:

```
ClearCollect(NewTable,
    AddColumns(Employee_Table,
        "Department_Name",LookUp(Department_Table,Department_ID=Employee_Table[@Department_ID],Department_Name)))
```

Then set the table's item to **NewTable**.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this solution

Comment: If you find this answer works for you, please mark it as accepted. Thank you!